# Is it possible to use 'shall' for intentions? is PEU wrong here?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, future-tense, will-shall

M.swan PEU (3rd edition-unit:217) says,

> " Topic: **announcing decisions: *will***
>   We often use *will* when we tell people about a decision as we make it.for instant if we're agreeing to do something.
>                 
>   e.g:1. OK. we'll buy the tickets.
>                        
>   2.The phone's ringing. I'll answer it.
>   *Shall* is not used in this way.
>                 
>   e.g:You can have it for $50. -OK.I'll buy it. (*NOT: I shall buy it*) "

According to this, we can't use *shall* (with first persons) for intentions or decisions which  made at the time of speaking.but the book 'Cambridge Grammar Of English' and these web seits( [1](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-will-and-shall)  , [2](http://www.grammaring.com/future-simple-for-intentions-offers-promises-and-decisions) ) say that *shall* can be used to announce intentions or decisions. *for example*,

- I don't want anyone with me.I **shall** do this on my own. (reference:CGE)
- I **shall** contact you again when I have further information.

So my questions is, is it possible to use **shall** for intentions or decisions as we make them(with I&we)?  [if the answer is Yes ,Why do PEU say "shall is not used for decisions "]

I searched on the internet and read lot of grammar book but I could not find a clear answer to this confusion.so any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There's a useful summary on [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/shall-versus-will), which points out that...

> *The British traditionally use **shall** to express **determination or intention** on the part of the speaker or someone other than the subject of the verb.*

But in practice [it's a declining usage everywhere](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20will%2CI%20shall&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20will%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20shall%3B%2Cc0) - particularly in recent decades, native Anglophones are much more likely to just place heavy stress on ***will*** to emphasise "resolute/defiant intention" over and above the standard "future tense" sense of the auxiliary verb.

When *Practical English Usage* says *"**shall** is not used for decisions"*, they're talking about the kind of "voluntary, unforced" decision you might make in a restaurant...

> 1: *"I **will** have the fillet steak"* (usually contracted to *"**I'll** have..."*)
>    2: *"I **shall** have the fillet steak"*

...where the first version is standard, and carries no implications beyond the fact that you've made a choice. The second version (which would be somewhat "unusual", particularly for AmE and younger speakers in general) is only likely to occur in contexts where the speaker for some reason wants to inject a note of defiance/determination (perhaps because whoever's paying the bill has asked his guests not to choose the most expensive items on the menu).

---

EDIT: There's also [this rather quirky BrE "rule"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/shall-or-will): use ***shall*** with ***I/we***, and ***will*** with ***you/he/she/it/they*** (except when expressing *determination,* in which case the usages are reversed). But as that Oxford Dictionaries link implies, in practice most people don't even know the "rule" (and most of those that *do* routinely ignore it anyway).

TL;DR: If your coursework *specifically* addresses "correct" use of ***shall***, and you have an exam to pass, remember and repeat whatever you were taught. If the distinction wasn't covered, or you're not taking an exam anyway, just use ***will*** in all cases.

Comment: Do you say *shall* can be used for decisions or intentions which are made at the moment of speaking (like [this site](http://www.grammaring.com/future-simple-for-intentions-offers-promises-and-decisions) says, But It can't be used for voluntary decisions,can it?

Comment: @Dinusha: In practice I think the best advice for *learners* is probably just "Always use **will**". We don't use ***shall*** so often now anyway, and increasing numbers of (esp, *younger*) native speakers either don't *know* the subtle differences in semantics/register, or have a different understanding of them from *other* native speakers. If you stick with ***will*** you'll probably never be "wrong", but it woiuld be almost impossible to learn how to reliably use ***shall*** in ways which would never strike at least *some* native speakers as "odd".

Comment: @Dinusha I wholeheartedly endorse FumbleFingers' advice, except in one circumstance: ***when you are taking an exam.*** The composers of examinations, alas, appear to be drawn exclusively from those who (having learned 'proper grammar' from teachers trained in the 1940s) have been careful not to notice anything that has occurred in the language for the last 70 years.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Exception to your rule: When trying to fend off a Balrog, use shall :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess *shall*  can't be used to express **willingness** with first person in affirmatives.  it may be what M.Swan has mentioned as "shall is not used in this way." Do you think *shall* can be used to express willingness in affirmatives (with I&we)?

Comment: @Dinusha: Here's [the "traditional rule"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/shall-or-will) - use ***shall*** with ***I/we***, and ***will*** with ***you/he/she/it/they*** (except when expressing *determination*, in which case the usages are reversed). StoneyB's comment notwithstanding, I don't think it's worth bothering with - just use ***will*** in all cases. It's not really worth trying to learn all the subtleties of where ***shall*** might still be used "correctly", but you might wish to note that ***will*** obviously pairs with ***willingness***.