# When to use Shall and when to use Can?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, modal-verbs, questions

I am confused how to use Shall and Can. 
For example:

```
Shall I commit the code

Can I commit the code
```

Which one of the above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each is correct in different contexts. It's not a question of "one is right and one is wrong".

> "Shall I do X?"

is an inquiry as to whether something *ought* to be done. You could safely rephrase it as "Do you want me to do X?" The underlying question is  "Would it be a good thing for me to do X?"

> "Can I do X"

taken literally, is a question as to whether the one asking is capable of doing X. You could alternatively put it as "Am I capable of doing X?"

However, "Can I do X?" is often casually used in place of

> "May I do X?"

Which would be safely rephrased as "Am I permitted/allowed to do X?" This distinction between "Can I" and "May I" can be seen in

> "Yes, of course you *can* [are physically able to] eat all the cookies in the jar, but you *may* not [you are not permitted to do so]."

Comment: It's also worth noting that "shall" has a depth of meaning and usage that isn't really in scope for this question. FumbleFingers answered this a while ago at http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44835/is-it-possible-to-use-shall-for-intentions-is-peu-wrong-here.